# how to write a Query Function to filter sales from "Data" sheet

Tags: google-sheets, filter, vlookup, spreadsheet, google-query-language

In cell B1, how to write a Query Function to filter sales from "Data" sheet,  When I paste any salesman list into A1:A9999 ,  it would shows sales amount for each salesman.

The result should be as follow:

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h2x-KgeBhOmiKpbx0EkWW6liZWMQ3w1mC7uTkCOy1tE/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in B1:

```
={"Q"; INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Data!B3:E, 4, 0)))}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works

Answer (score 2):

**Here's another solution:**

`={"Sales"; arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",iferror(vlookup(A2:A,query(Data!A1:E,"Select B, sum(E) where B is not null group by B label sum(E) ''",0),2,false),"Not Found"),""))}`

- The difference for this formula is that it will return your selected salesman's total sale (if ever your data will have multiple salesman entries)

**Example:** (I modified your data sheet for this example)

[image]

### Output:

[image]